# Delegates of types, or how to give a clumsy type a better name

Tags: c#, types

In a project I'm working on, I use complicated `Dictionary` objects a lot. Often, there are a lot of declarations like:

```
var d1 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<string>>>();
var d2 = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, List<object>>();
```

Between typecasts and passing parameters and what not, this gets annoying. What I'd like to do is something like this, using an imaginary keyword "typedel":

```
typedel ListDict = Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<string>>>();
typedel PolyDict = Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, List<object>>();

var d1 = new ListDict();
var d2 = new PolyDict();
```

So that I do not need to type the long `Dictionary` declarations every time - so what I want is something like defining shorthand abbreviations for a type name. How can I do this in the simplest way (using the fewest lines of code)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a "typedef" that you want to use a lot, you can just create a class that derives from the appropriate base class, as in @Ed S's answer:

```
class MyData : Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<string>>>
{   
}
```

However, this is not the same as what most people consider a typedef: you are introducing a new type, which has implications for things like reflection, `typeof`, the `is` operator, etc. The distinction may or may not matter to you, but it is there.

Within a single source file, however, you can use the second form of the `using` clause to do a real typedef:

```
using ListDict = Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<string>>>();
using PolyDict = Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, List<object>>();
```

In either case, while using a "typedef" will definitely save you typing, don't discount the benefits of seeing the types spelled out explicitly in your code. This is the same reason why articles such as [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/08/17/215740.aspx) recommend using `List<Foo>` over a custom `FooCollection : List<Foo>` -- with the explicit generic version you *know* what type of collection it is any what methods it exposes.

Comment: Hehe, just added that to mine as you were posting. +1 then

Comment: Ah, thank you! Your second suggestion was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

```
class MyData : Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<string>>>
{

}
```

You could also do this, but you would have to do it in every file which uses `MyData`, and that is probably suboptimial.

```
using MyData = Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<string>>>;
```

Answer (score 1):

And, just for laughs...

```
    static Func<T> Magic<T>(Func<T> f) { return f; }
    static Func<T> Creator<T>() where T : new() { return () => new T(); }
    ...
    var ListDict = Magic(() => new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<string>>>());
    var PolyDict = Creator<Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, List<object>>>();
    var d1 = ListDict();
    var d2 = PolyDict();
```